# How to convert jars to dependencies and deploy them to a local repository?

Tags: maven, jsp, servlets, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

My question is about mavenization, well the pupose is how to convert jars to dependencies from jsp servlet project to maven, i have succeeded to convert the project to maven with pom.xml file,

pom.xml generated:

```
 <project.....>
    <groupId>Calender</groupId>
    <artifactId>Calender</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </project>
```

Then i have opened the terminal and tried to this command and it get build success just below the command maven install:

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=target\Calender-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  -DpomFile=pom.xml  -Dsources=target\Calender-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ Calender ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Calender\target\Calender-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\h.khadhri\.m2\repository\Calender\Calender\2.0\Calender-2.0.jar
[INFO] Installing D:\Calender\pom.xml to C:\Users\h.khadhri\.m2\repository\Calender\Calender\2.0\Calender-2.0.pom
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------
```

in my project i have external jars should i convert them to dependency ?

Comment: Use a correct path?

Comment: @Meo i have updated my post, you were right.

Comment: Do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

are the jars you have currently in your project on the global nexus repository? if so simply add a  section to your pom file.

[maven dependency documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)